# How would I use WordNet to build a recommendation system?

Tags: system, wordnet

I've got a set of queries and notes and I'd like recommend similar queries and notes based on any given entry, using WordNet.  Where would I begin to learn how to do that?  What language(s) should I use for something like this, what should I study, etc.

I'm a self taught programmer, a beginner, but I'm willing to learn, ask questions and read.

Is this something that is feasible i.e. using wordnet to create a recommender system?

What if I want to cluster these queries in a single document; say as a brief overview or outline?

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit general, but I'd say the first step is to choose a programming language, and then go and evaluate [its WordNet bindings](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/). You don't actually need to use an API if you are comfortable in your language, as the WordNet files are all fairly easy to parse.

But if starting from scratch, with no strong leanings to any language, I'd suggest first looking at Python and the NLTK library. NLTK has a [WordNet sub-library](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html) but will also give you other functions you are going to need. And there are also at least a couple of books on it.

Comment: @Veta, if it helps click the up arrow :-)  (And if you don't get any better answers after a few days, click the tick: your question is a bit too general to have any clearly correct answer. You can also change your choice of correct answer later on.)